# Using MongoDB in Atlas, cant connect to replicas

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-atlas

Been following this [tutorial](https://blog.bitsrc.io/build-a-login-auth-app-with-mern-stack-part-1-c405048e3669) to set up a MERN stack database(see part iii).

I have created a New Project on Atlas using AWS as my cloud provider and Sandbox as my plan type. I have added myself as an admin user and entered in the correct IP address in the corresponding fields in Atlas. Ive tried to connect to the database using this URI connection string `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-echb9.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority` in my Mac terminal.

***Left username and password out for obvious reasons but in terminal I typed out all the information.
When I try to connect I get an error that says: [Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4TZ2.png)

Also, both my `mongoDb` shell and server are the same version so I know thats not the issue. Any help? If you need more info, please let me know. New here.

Comment: Is it primary and secondary setup is done properly??

Comment: How do I do that/set that up?